# Sort by meta key on archive page

Tags: wp-query, loop, sort

I am trying to sort an archive page using a meta key value (which happens to be a Unix timestamp).  Currently I have the posts listed on the page by their WordPress creation date.  I want to use the meta key - which is a different date than the WP creation date.

The code is pretty simple at this point, its just using The Loop to display the posts using a template:

```
<?php

while (have_posts()) : the_post();


Template code here


endwhile;

?>
```

How do I get the posts to show up by the meta value dates instead of the WP creation date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter the main query before it is run. The action runs on every query, use the [Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to target specific queries.

```
function wpd_sort_by_meta( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'your_meta_key' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpd_sort_by_meta' );
```

Comment: Thanks for this link and details [Never use quer_post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts/1755#1755)  @Milo

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help, this was the solution for me!